# How to reduce whitespace of left and right side of my screen?

Tags: android

How do I minimize spacing on left and right side of image view? My xml file shows much space on left and right side of image. My screen looks like this:

[image]

and I want to make it like this:

[image: image2]

How do I reduce spacing on left and right side of images?

```
<LinearLayout 

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/imagebgborder"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/imagebgborder"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/img3"

        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/imagebgborder"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txt3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this and had success using a TableLayout instead for the main content (your 3 items).
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

**Updated code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- NEW LINEAR LAYOUT -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >

        <!-- Your individual items go here -->

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayoutPlacard"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img1"
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="ITEM 1"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img1"
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="ITEM 2"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img1"
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="ITEM 3"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: My bad, I was working on another project and didn't test this out.  Try my update above that uses TableLayout.